# Haskell Prime-testing confusion

Tags: haskell, primality-test

So I'm totally new to Haskell, hope it doesn't show too much. By any means, I was trying to create a function to determine if a number is prime. The basic idea is this: Given a number, see if it is divisible by any other number less than it. If so, return false. If not, it's prime, return true. The code so far (that is known to be working) is this:

```
divisible :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
divisible x 2 = even x
divisible x y = ((x `mod` y) /= 0) && not (divisible x (y-1))
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime x = not (even x) && not (divisible x (x-1))
```

Produces:

```
ghci> isPrime 9
False
ghci> isPrime 13
True
```

What I'd like to do is optimize this a bit, since I only need to check values less than or equal to sqrt(x). The problem is, when I try and implement this, stuff gets crazy:

```
isPrime x = not (even x) && not (divisible x (ceiling(sqrt(fromIntegral(x-1)))))
```

Besides the fact that it looks terrible (I said I was new), it doesn't give the correct result:

```
ghci> isPrime 9
False
ghci> isPrime 13
False
```

I'm trying to figure out what changed, because:

```
ghci> ceiling(sqrt(13))
4
```

Seems to be giving me the correct number. I know this is a small problem, but I'm seriously confused...

Comment: Protip: instead of testing for `sqrt(d) <= n`, test for `d*d <= n`. Works in any language and avoids messing with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You got your conditions mixed up:

```
divisible x y = ((x `mod` y) /= 0) && not (divisible x (y-1))
```

should be

```
divisible x y = (x `mod` y) == 0 || divisible x (y-1)
```

for the test to work.

As is, your `divisible` function expands e.g.

```
divisible 21 5 = (21 `mod` 5 /= 0) && not (divisible 21 4)
               = (21 `mod` 5 /= 0) && not ((21 `mod` 4 /= 0) && not (divisible 21 3))
               = not ((21 `mod` 4 /= 0) && not ((21 `mod` 3 /= 0) && not (divisible 21 2)))
               = not (True && not (False && not (divisible 21 3)))
               = not (not False)
               = False
```

since `` 21 `mod` 3 == 0 ``, and `isPrime 21` evaluates to `True` with the square root bound.

However, I get

```
*StrangePrime> isPrime 9
True
*StrangePrime> isPrime 13
True
```

with your code using the square root.

Without the square root, it happened to work for odd numbers, because the difference between an odd composite and any of its divisors is always even. Unfolding `divisible` a few steps for `n = p*m`, where `p` is the smallest prime factor of the odd composite `n`, we see

```
divisible n (n-1) = n `mod` (n-1) /= 0 && not (divisible n (n-2))
                  = not (divisible n (n-2))
                  = not (n `mod` (n-2) /= 0 && not (divisible n (n-3)))
                  = not (not (divisible n (n-3)))
                  = not^2 (divisible n (n-3))
```

and inductively

```
divisible n (n-1) = not^(k-1) (divisible n (n-k))
```

if there are no divisors of `n` larger than `n-k`. Now, in the above situation, the largest divisor of `n` is `m = n - (p-1)*m`, so we obtain

```
divisible n (n-1) = not^((p-1)*m-1) (divisible n m)
                  = not^((p-1)*m-1) (n `mod` m /= 0 && not (...))
```

But `` n `mod` m == 0 ``, so we have

```
divisible n (n-1) = not^((p-1)*m-1) False
```

Since `p` is odd, `p-1` is even, and hence so is `(p-1)*m`, so altogether we have an odd number of `not`s, which is the same as one `not`, giving

```
divisible n (n-1) = True
isPrime n = not (even n) && not (divisible n (n-1)) = True && not True = False
```

If `p` is an odd prime, the unfolding reaches `divisible p (p-1) = not^(p-3) (divisible p (p - (p-2)))`. `p-3` is even, `divisible p 2` is `even p`, which is `False`.

Generally, consider `divisible n s` for an odd `n`, and let `d` be the largest divisor of `n` not exceeding `s`, if `n` is composite, or `d = 2` if `n` is prime. The unfolding of `divisible n s` still proceeds the same way

```
divisible n s = not^k (divisible n (s-k))
```

while no divisor has been found and `s-k > 2`. So in the case of a composite `n`, we find

```
divisible n s = not^(s-d) (divisible n d)
              = not^(s-d) (n `mod` d /= 0 && not (...))
              = not^(s-d) False
              = odd (s-d)
              = even s     -- since d is odd, as a divisor of an odd number
```

and in the case of an odd prime `n`,

```
divisible n s = not^(s-2) (divisible n 2)
              = not^(s-2) (even n)
              = not^(s-2) False
              = odd s
```

So `divisible n s` measures the parity of the distance of `s` to the next smaller divisor of `n` or to 2, whichever is larger. When `s` was `n-1`, the starting point was always even, so it worked out correctly, but `ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral (n-1)))` can be odd, in which case the results are flipped and composites are declared prime and vice versa.

You can make your `divisible` function work for the primality test of odd numbers with a square root bound if you make sure that the first call gets an even second argument (so if `ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral (n-1)))` is odd, start at `ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral (n-1))) + 1`), but the logic of that function is confusing, and its name doesn't correctly describe its results.

A more idiomatic way to write it would be

```
isPrime n = and [n `mod` k /= 0 | k <- [2 .. ceiling (sqrt $ fromIntegral n)]]
```

The test becomes more efficient when one skips candidate divisors that are already known to be nondivisors from prior tests, easy is skipping all even numbers except 2,

```
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n = all ((/= 0) . (n `mod`)) (2 : [3, 5 .. ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral n))])
```

slightly more involved, but still more efficient is also skipping multiples of 3

```
isPrime n = all ((/= 0) . (n `mod`)) (takeWhile (<= bound) (2:3:scanl (+) 5 (cycle [2,4])))
  where
    bound = ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral (n-1)))
```

In the same vein one can eliminate the multiples of more small primes from the trial divisors, each gaining a bit of efficiency, but at the cost of a more complicated wheel, e.g. also eliminating multiples of 5 leads to

```
isPrime n = all ((/= 0) . (n `mod`)) (takeWhile (<= bound) (2:3:5: scanl (+) 7 (cycle [4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6])))
  where
    bound = ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral (n-1)))
```

Comment: Thank you much, I appreciate the in-depth solution.

Comment: EDIT: That being said, does anybody know why the sqrt isn't working correctly?

Comment: Not working in what way? It's the `not`s that cause it, in the original, it just turned out to work for odd numbers because there's then always an odd number of steps to the largest divisor. I'll add that to my answer in more detail. By the way, your `isPrime` says 2 isn't prime.

Comment: Haha, woops. Thank you for the in-depth explanation, don't think I would have figured that out on my own.

Comment: I came to the solution that you propsed first for eliminating 2 and i further optimised by adding a 'odd n &&' part in front of the 'all ...' section. It's more simple than the later solution imho, and eliminates half of the non primes early.

Comment: @erdeszt `odd n` is equivalent to ``n `mod` 2 /= 0`` (it uses `rem` instead of `mod`, which makes it a little bit more efficient). Since `all` stops trying as soon as it found the first failure, and `2` is the first in the list of potential divisors, you don't gain anything from adding an `odd n &&` before the `all` (if you change the `mod` to `rem`).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
divisibleBy :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Bool
divisibleBy x y = mod x y == 0

isPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
isPrime x = or $ map (divisibleBy x) [2..(x-1)]
```

`divisibleBy` is a simple test of divisibility. `isPrime` performs this test on all integers between 1 and x, returning true if `x` is divisible by any of those integers. You might change the upper bound to root `x`, as you've done in your code, but otherwise this works.

Comment: Or `isPrime x = any (divisibleBy x) [2..(x-1)]`.